# Can show the comments writing in the create table command?

Tags: mysql, comments

We can write comment to create a table:

```
create database `mytest`;
use `mytest`;
create table `mytest` (
/* mytest mytest */ 
  `code` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
```

How can show the comment `/* mytest mytest */` in create table command?

```
show create table mytest;
+--------+------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                                                                                  |
+--------+------------------------------------+
| mytest | CREATE TABLE `mytest` (
  `code` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: See also the `COMMENT` clause when defining a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of comment is not stored in the table definition, so you can't get it with SQL.

A workaround is to do this :

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.tests (
    c1 INT
) COMMENT = 'Just a comment';

SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.tests;
```

That gives :

```
CREATE TABLE `tests` (
  `c1` int DEFAULT NULL
) COMMENT='Just a comment' ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Or better :

```
SELECT ALL table_comment 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name = 'tests';
```

Giving :

```
table_comment
Just a comment
```

You can also have column-level comments :

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.tests (
    c1 INT COMMENT 'c1''s comment',
    c2 INT COMMENT 'c2''s comment'
);

SELECT ALL column_name, column_comment
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name = 'tests';
```

Gives :

```
column_name column_comment
c1          c1's comment
c2          c2's comment
```